# Lightning node with two channels to peer not able to select funded channel

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning

### Description

I have two peers: p1 and p2 running lightning-core

p1 opened a channel to p2 and p2 opened another channel to p1.

Now p2 has two channels. One with outbound funding and one with 0. Output of `listfunds`:

```
"channels": [      
      {
         "peer_id": "02e7b2196a87513ef322fc2c23d5739ed4ac696a9010a855dbfe7185fe8e133c93",
         "connected": true,
         "state": "CHANNELD_NORMAL",
         "short_channel_id": "2410508x70x0",
         "channel_sat": 0,
         "our_amount_msat": "0msat",
         "channel_total_sat": 113495,
         "amount_msat": "113495000msat",
         "funding_txid": "1f5284dbfcaf76e8a333c1c607465a9474294f43cfbcbbb34504d97aac2189a4",
         "funding_output": 0
      },
      {
         "peer_id": "02e7b2196a87513ef322fc2c23d5739ed4ac696a9010a855dbfe7185fe8e133c93",
         "connected": true,
         "state": "CHANNELD_NORMAL",
         "short_channel_id": "2410509x222x0",
         "channel_sat": 90433,
         "our_amount_msat": "90433000msat",
         "channel_total_sat": 90433,
         "amount_msat": "90433000msat",
         "funding_txid": "befde7cbd4965f21fe9df3a1f06eb1968109a7246457aabed58bfe39f6694b08",
         "funding_output": 0
      }
   ]
```

### Problem

Now I tried to `pay` a 1000msat p1 invoice from p2 and get the error:

> failed: WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE (WIRE_TEMPORARY_CHANNEL_FAILURE: Capacity exceeded - HTLC fee: 183sat)

I think this is because p2 tries to send using the not funded channel `2410508x70x0`. Because if I delete this channel, all works as expected.

Additional information:

Also `getroute` shows that channel 2410508x70x0 is used:

```
$ lightning-cli --testnet getroute 02e7b2196a87513ef322fc2c23d5739ed4ac696a9010a855dbfe7185fe8e133c93 1000 0
{
   "route": [
      {
         "id": "02e7b2196a87513ef322fc2c23d5739ed4ac696a9010a855dbfe7185fe8e133c93",
         "channel": "2410508x70x0",
         "direction": 1,
         "msatoshi": 1000,
         "amount_msat": "1000msat",
         "delay": 9,
         "style": "tlv"
      }
   ]
}
```

### Questions

- Why does p2 does not auto select the funded channel?
- Is there a way to select the channel? I did not find an option for `pay`.

Comment: Is it possible that https://blockstream.info/testnet/tx/befde7cbd4965f21fe9df3a1f06eb1968109a7246457aabed58bfe39f6694b08 didn't have three confirmations yet, when you tried to make that payment?—Does it work meanwhile?

Comment: Tried once again with the same channel, still the same error. (the one I deleted was from a previous test).

Comment: Please look at additional information. Also, `getroute` shows that the wrong channel is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Why does p2 not auto-select the funded channel?

In this case, I guess that the pay plugin is smart enough to select the peer with the correct channel, or better is not able to choose the right channel of the peer. I guess this is a limitation of the pay plugin, also if I do not remember the code, maybe if you open an issue we can take a look at what is going on in your case!

- Is there a way to select the channel? I did not find an option for payment.

Yes you can use the `sendpay` command that allows you to specify the route, this is a low-level command but it is a good way to have the power to choose the route